# how to print multiple numbers to words

Tags: c++

in my code, i don't understand why zero doesn't print i did all possible solutions that I know but it doesn't print zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int digits; 
    int numberOne = 0;
    int integer;
    
    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin>>digits;
    while (digits != 0) {
        numberOne = (numberOne * 10) + (digits % 10);
        digits /= 10;
    }
    for (integer = numberOne; integer > 0; integer = integer / 10){
        switch (integer  % 10) {
            case 0:
                cout<<"Zero\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout<<"One\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Two\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Three\n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"Four\n";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout<<"Five\n";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout<<"Six\n";
                break;
            case 7:
                cout<<"Seven\n";
                break;
            case 8:
                cout<<"Eight\n";
                break;
            case 9:
                cout<<"Nine\n";
                break;
        }
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

zero doesn't print how do I fix it?
Expected output is 900 (nine zero zero) but zero doesn't print in my case. help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it print zero? Look at your loop

```
for (integer = numberOne; integer > 0; integer = integer / 10){
```

If `integer` equals zero then the loop is never entered. You need to be a bit smarter in your loop. How about counting digits?

```
int num_digits = 0;
while (digits != 0) {
    numberOne = (numberOne * 10) + (digits % 10);
    digits /= 10;
    ++num_digits;
}
```

Now that you have the number of digits, you can use that in your second loop

```
for (integer = numberOne; num_digits > 0; integer = integer / 10, --num_digits) {
    ...
}
```

You still need to treat zero as a special case, because if the user enters `0` then `num_digits` will equal zero and you again won't print anything. I'll leave you to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this line:

```
for (integer = numberOne; integer > 0; integer = integer / 10){
```

the loop continues only if `integer>0`. Therefore you never see "Zero".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int digits; 
    int arrayLength = 10;  
    
    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin>>digits;
    
    string reverse_number[arrayLength]; //array to store the string of numbers like "Zero"
    int array_counter=0;
    while (digits != 0) {
        switch (digits  % 10) {
            case 0:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Zero";
                break;
            case 1:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "One";
                break;
            case 2:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Two";
                break;
            case 3:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Three";
                break;
            case 4:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Four";
                break;
            case 5:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Five";
                break;
            case 6:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Six";
                break;
            case 7:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                reverse_number[array_counter++] = "Nine";
                break;
        }
        digits /=10;
    }
        int num_digits = array_counter;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_digits; i++) {
            cout << reverse_number[--array_counter] <<" ";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The reason why your zeros are not showing while doing for 900 is because when you are reversing 900 to 009, there is no condition mentioned to handle the leading zeros in 009 which are just ignored. For this the best approach would be to store them somewhere else like in a string or an array. You can also just store the number words directly to an array while you are converting, that way you wont lose the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already addressed the main problem with your code.
This answer focus on the post's title: how to print multiple numbers to words?

- First, I would consider using an array of strings instead of a switch.
  In order to retrieve a string for a given digit, you would just index that array.
  (see `digits[c - '0']` below)
- Also, if you are allowed to convert a number to a string, the code would reduce to walking that string and converting each character to a word.
  You could read the number directly as a string from the standard input, or use `std::to_string` on an integer.
  Notice also that, when reading a character `c` from the a string of digits, `c - '0'` gives you an integer betweeen `0` and `9`, which you can use as the array index.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sKMK516er)

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // to_string

std::array<std::string, 10> digits{
    "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"
};

void digits_to_words(int n) {
    for (unsigned char c : std::to_string(n)) {
        std::cout << digits[c - '0'] << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int n : { 0, 5, 105, 900 }) {
        std::cout << "Number: " << n << "\n";
        digits_to_words(n);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```